# Trying to use for loop and replace it with some value

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "DateCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DateCollectionViewCell
        //Calendar as I have changed the resuse Identifer.
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        cell.DateLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
        cell.dateSubTitle.text = "500"

        monthsforselect()
       // self.newday = ["\(year)\\/\(cm)\\/\(indexPath.row - PositionIndex + 1)"]
        newday = "\(year)\\/\(cm)\\/\(indexPath.row - PositionIndex + 1)"
      //  print(newday)

      //  print(ele, element)
//        if newday == "2018\\/03\\/29"{
//            cell.dateSubTitle.text = "GOOD"
//        }
```

This is my `cellForItemAt` and I am trying to pass value in `Cell.DateSubtitle.text` from an `array`. Below are the `array` contains two `array`. `self.date_listArray` and `self.actual_balanceArray`. New day is the string which contains my calendar date. Below that I have `date_subtitle` `label` to pass some value on proper date I want to check the value if date that is coming from "New day"  `array` Above cell for item In `self.date_listArray` and it matches change the `cell.dateSubtitle.text` with value in `self.actual_balanceArray` and if not matched pass "" (empty string ).   This is my code for for loop[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLYRT.png)  Please do check the image link below and I have also check with passing one string and it works fine but not able to check with array. Thanks in advance to friend!

```
for element in self.actual_balanceArray{
//      print("elemenst: \(element)")
 }
 for ele in self.date_listArray{
if self.date_listArray.contains("\(self.newday)"){
print(self.date_listArray.index(of: self.newday))
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more , i did not get what are you trying to explain please.

Comment: Sure. Thanks. I have calendar on on below each date I have label named Date_subtitle on which I want to pass value which I am getting after matching proper date date_listarray with newday(it contains the date of calendar). If date matches I want to pass the value to subtitle label from actual_balance array. the value matched with datelistarray and calendar date(newday) will get the value for subtitle label from actual balance array at same index path. Please do check the link https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLYRT.png and you will get idea for it

Comment: So you mean to say that you need to compare value of two array.? If the value from the array matches you need to use that.? Am i right.?

Comment: Yes right and I want to pass the value  but that value we will get from actual balance array. and that value need to pass on proper date. Please have look on image link

Comment: Can you show me the two array which you want to compare, so that i can try to make a code for you. The value of array with the format.

Comment: Yes. This is my self.date_listarray : (
    "2018/04/01",
    "2018/04/04",
    "2018/04/04",
    "2018/04/08")     this is my actual_balancearray : (
    "3732.0",
    "1392.0",
    "4953.0",
    "96.0",
    "2648.0",
    "2677.0",
    "344.0",
    "13376.0",
    "328.0",
    "808.0",
    "808.0") This is my newday string() which contains the date of calendar till last date of month : (2018\/04\/-5
2018\/04\/-4
2018\/04\/-3
2018\/04\/-2
2018\/04\/-1
2018\/04\/0
2018\/04\/1
2018\/04\/2
2018\/04\/3
2018\/04\/4
2018\/04\/5
2018\/04\/6
2018\/04\/7
2018\/04\/8)

Comment: Can i know now what to do be done in this array.?I mean this three array. I am still in confusion.?

Comment: Please ignore the actual_balancearray.

Comment: So you need to check if the date in date_listarray is present in new_day (which is of type string or array).?

Comment: Newday is type of string() we need to check in date_listarray array

Comment: so you want to check that the string contains the element of array.? is that right. For Eg. date_listarray have 4-5 dates, you need to check if your string newday contains any of the element from that  date_listarray.?

Comment: Yes that is perfect

Comment: Added the answer. Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can find if String contains the Value from the array like:**

```
    let arrDate = ["2018/04/01", "2018/04/04", "2018/04/04", "2018/04/08"]

    let newdayString = "(2018/04/01 2018/04/02 2018/04/03 2018/04/04 2018/04/05 2018/04/06 2018/04/07 2018/04/08)"

    for date in arrDate{

        if newdayString.range(of:date) != nil {
           print("string Present")
        }else{
            print("not present")
        }
    }
```

Hope this Help!

Comment: Thanks friend and it worked. A small issue the array which I have in view did load that takes data from api and when I print that array in cell for item I get empty but in view did load I get value

Comment: pleasure helping you.Sorry You mean to say that the value is not fetched in cell right.? It might be a problem like you print it early before the response is complete from api, Sometimes it take a much more time to come response from api. An if it worked for you do not forget to upvote it  after approval. @gaus

Comment: The above code is working but I have one more issue. I have one array on view did load which contains some value when I print it in view did load i get values but when I print in cellforitem it gives me empty array

Comment: are u fetching the data from api once again in cellforitem in tableView?

Comment: no in any case I get api array data empty in collection view cell

Comment: can you show me the code what you have implemented, so that i can help you in that of cell for item where you are getting empty array.

Comment: @gaus I am not sure why have you un accepted my answer after accepting it previously, I though it worked for you

Comment: I am sorry I am new in this community I didn't know how to use the tag and answering by tick mark. really sorry. @Abhirajsinh Thakore

Comment: Not an issue @gaus , I am happy that the code helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this I am not allowed to comment any more//
**this is from view did load**

```
    do {
Alamofire.request("my api link", method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON
                    {(response) in
if let json = response.result.value as NSDictionary{                                                   
self.data_Array = json.value(forKey: "Data") as! NSArray
self.date_listArray = self.data_Array.value(forKey: "date_list") as! NSArray
}catch{
print("error")
}
```

**This is my cell**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "DateCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DateCollectionViewCell
        print(self.date_listArray)
//the above print gives me empty string          

}
```